# using linq select from list data where

Tags: c#, .net, linq

One `Book` has list of `Tag` objects. Using `linq` I want to select list of books where any tag name contains specified filter.

```
string genre; // filter
List<Book> books = repository.GetBooks();

foreach(Book book in books.Where(x=>x.Tags.Any())) //I'm stuck here
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to see if any tag name is equal to the filter:

```
books.Where(book => book.Tags.Any(tag => tag == genre))
```

or use Contains method:

```
books.Where(book => book.Tags.Contains(genre))
```

assuming `Tags` property returns a sequence of `string`. If `Tag` is a user-defined object, use:

```
books.Where(book => book.Tags.Any(tag => tag.Name == genre))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
var results = books.Where(x => x.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == genre))
```

Or this:

```
var results = books.Where(x => x.Tags.Select(t => t.Name).Contains(genre))
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
foreach(Book book in books.Where(x=>x.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == "tag-name")))
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Book.Tags` is a collection of `Tag` objects, you should use `Any` and pass lambda expression:

```
foreach(Book book in books.Where(x=>x.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == filter)))
```

If `Book.Tags` is a collection of `string`s, you should use `Contains` method:

```
foreach(Book book in books.Where(x=>x.Tags.Contains(filter)))
```